# SQL query select from multiple tables problem

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

I have a mySQL database containing where Schools located in different countries provide training (the product) in different cars, with different objectives.

```
SCHOOLS
id| schoolname | 
----------------------------------
1  | Pete’s Driving school      |
2  | Karen’s Driving school     | 
3  | John’s Driving school      |
4  | Donald’s Driving school    | 

CARS
id| carbrand | 
----------------------------------
1  | Buick     |
2  | Mercedes  | 
3  | Tesla     |
4  | Audi      | 

PROVIDES (PROVIDES THIS TRAINING)
id| name | 
----------------------------------
1  | Get License         |
2  | Practise driving    | 
3  | Maneuvering         |
4  | Winter training     | 

LOCATIONS
id| name | 
----------------------------------
1  | USA     |
2  | UK      | 
3  | France  |
4  | Japan   |
```

I also have these tables telling me which schools have which cars, which location, and provide which training:

```
SCHOOL_OWNS
id| schoolid | carsid
----------------------------------
1  | 1     | 2
2  | 1     | 1
3  | 2     | 1
4  | 3     | 2

SCHOOL_PROVIDES
id| schoolid | providesid
----------------------------------
1  | 1     | 2
2  | 1     | 3
3  | 2     | 1
4  | 3     | 2

SCHOOL_LOCATIONS
id| schoolid | locationsid
----------------------------------
1  | 1     | 2
2  | 2     | 4
3  | 2     | 1
4  | 3     | 2
```

My products which I'm trying to select and output..

```
PRODUCT
id| productname | schoolid | carid | locationid | price
----------------------------------
1  | Product1 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 400 USD
2  | Product2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 300 USD
3  | Product3 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 200 USD
4  | Product4 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 100 USD
```

My question is now how to write a JOIN query to get what I'm looking for. This is doing my head in and not even sure where to start or if the way I have done it is a recommended way of setting it up?

I’m trying to create a SQL query that lets me select and sort depending on three criteria, car brand, provides and location.

I have on the top of the page three dropdown menus "CARS", "PROVIDES SERVICE" and "LOCATION".

What SQL Query could match these two scenarios?! Thanks I'm a bit lost..

```
1. If I want to  display all products that fulfill all 
these three criteria (Buick, Maneuvering, Japan) 
cars=1&provides=3&location=4

    Output (only one product meet this criteria): 
    Product1 | Karen’s Driving school | 400 USD

-------------------

2. And if I only want display all products that provide ‘practise driving’ ?cars=&provides=2&location= , 
Then all products should show that have a company that provides “practice driving” ..

        Output (only one two products meet this criteria): 
        Product1 | Karen’s Driving school | 400 USD
        Product3 | John’s Driving school | 200 USD
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you can't make those joins since you do not have foreign keys in your tables.

as an example.. linking cars id to a provides id will not work, so it can't reach that table an easy way... you will need a foreign key or make a sub table to make it easier for yourself!

Comment: Thanks for input! I will look this up.

Comment: The relationships between the main tables are many-to-many, this is why there are several junction tables to provide the linkeage between the main tables.